# index of nilpotency of an endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us assume that $E$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ of finite dimension $n$  and  $f \in L(E)$ (endormphism over $E$ that is linear maps from $E$ to $E$) such that for all $x\in E$ there exists an $n (x) \in \mathbb N$ we have $f^{n(x)}(x)=0$. I have no idea of how to prove that $f^{n}(x)=0$ for all $x\in E$... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $\dim(f^k(E)) < \dim (f^{k-1}(E))$ whenever $f^{k-1} \neq 0$.  It follows that $\dim(f^n(E))\leq 0$.

---

Consider first the case of a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$

Note that $f$ is an endomorphism on $f^{k-1}(E)$ for any $k \geq 1$.  It follows that $f$ has a complex eigenvector $v \in E$.  So, $f(v) = \lambda v$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.  If $\lambda \neq 0$, then $n(v)$ cannot exist, which is a contradiction.  So, $f(v) = 0$.

Thus, $f$ has a non-trivial kernel over $f^{k-1}(E)$.  Thus, $\dim(f^{k-1}(E)) < \dim(f^k(E))$.

Similarly, if $E$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is invariant of some subspace $f^{k-1}(E)$ of dimension $1$ or $2$. We may similarly conclude that the kernel must be non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your Hint, are meaning $N=max_{i \in [1,n]}\{n(v_{i})\}$?

Comment: That is what I meant.  I realize now that this part of the hint is, however, unnecessary.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: Thank you so much for this nice proof :)